# Java: JDOM.XMLOutputter don't overwrite XML File when looking to make multiple changes in a row

Tags: java, xml, jdom-2

### Explanation

I'm making **program that use a *XML* file to save some values to use as settings**, and **only need to read and modify the element values** in the *XML*. The **code is written in *Java*** and I'm **using *[JDOM 2.0.6.1](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/)*** to manage the *XML* file, followed [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_jdom_parser.htm).

**The code works when overwrite any element in the XML, but just 1 time**. If make **multiple operations** to modify any value, the program **start appending a new tree with the changes**, which should not happen and would be the problem.

The default XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>25</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
```

The Java code:

```java
public class FileHandler {

    private final Writer settingsWriter;
    private final XMLOutputter xmlOutput;
    private final Document settingsDoc;
    private final Element settingsElement;


    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Path settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
              FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE),
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();

        setElementValue("time-work", "5");
        setElementValue("time-work", "10");
        setElementValue("time-work", "30");
    }

    public void setElementValue(String element, String newValue) throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Element groupElement = settingsElement.getChild(element.startsWith("time")? "time":"auto-start"),
                toChangeElement = groupElement.getChild(element);

        toChangeElement.setText(newValue);
        xmlOutput.output(settingsDoc, settingsWriter);
    }

    /*More code, irrelevant for the post*/
}
```

### Examples

#### Example 1 (Works)

```java
    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Path settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
              FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE),
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();

        setElementValue("time-work", "5");
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
```

#### Example 2 (Works)

```java
    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Path settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
              FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE),
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();

        setElementValue("start-rest", "2");
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>25</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>2</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
```

#### Example 3 (Fail)

```java
    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Path settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
              FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE),
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();

        setElementValue("time-work", "5");
        setElementValue("time-work", "10");
        setElementValue("time-work", "30");
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>10</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>30</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
```

#### Example 4 (Fail)

```java
    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Path settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
              FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE),
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();

        setElementValue("time-work", "5");
        setElementValue("time-break", "10");
        setElementValue("time-rest", "30");
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>10</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>10</time-break>
    <time-rest>30</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
```

#### Example 5 (Fail)

```java
    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Path settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
              FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE),
              StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();

        setElementValue("time-work", "5");
        setElementValue("start-break", "false");
        setElementValue("time-interval", "2");
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>true</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>3</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>false</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <time>
    <time-work>5</time-work>
    <time-break>5</time-break>
    <time-rest>15</time-rest>
    <time-interval>2</time-interval>
  </time>
  <auto-start>
    <start-work>true</start-work>
    <start-break>false</start-break>
    <start-rest>true</start-rest>
  </auto-start>
</settings>
```

### What I tried

Tried to close the writer and use re-building the "*Document **settingsDoc***" inside the function.

Everything I tried ended in the same result, appending a new *XML* tree **after overwriting just 1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Alredy Solved

So, for anyone that find this question, the solution I use was:

```java
public class FileHandler {

    private final Writer settingsWriter;
    private final XMLOutputter xmlOutput;
    private final Document settingsDoc;
    private final Element settingsElement;
    private final FileChannel settingsChannel;
    private final Path settingsPath;


    FileHandler() throws IOException, JDOMException {

        settingsPath = Paths.get("res/settings/settings.xml");
        File settingsFile = settingsPath.toFile();
        boolean settingsExist = settingsFile.createNewFile();
        settingsChannel = FileChannel.open(settingsPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        settingsWriter = Channels.newWriter(
                settingsChannel,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());

        if (settingsExist) createSettings();

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        settingsDoc = saxBuilder.build(settingsFile);
        settingsElement = settingsDoc.getRootElement();
    }

    /*Irrelevant code for the answer*/

    public void setElementValues(boolean[] newStart, String[] newTexts) throws IOException, JDOMException {

        Element timeElement = settingsElement.getChild("time"),
                autoStartElement = settingsElement.getChild("auto-start");
        List<Element> timeElements = timeElement.getChildren(),
                        autoStartElements = autoStartElement.getChildren();

        for (int index = 0; index < autoStartElements.size(); ++index) {
            autoStartElements.get(index).setText(String.valueOf(newStart[index]));
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < timeElements.size(); ++index) {
            timeElements.get(index).setText(newTexts[index]);
        }

        settingsChannel.truncate(0);
        settingsWriter.flush();
        settingsChannel.force(true);
        xmlOutput.output(settingsDoc, settingsWriter);
        settingsWriter.flush();
        settingsChannel.force(true);
    }
```

### Explanation

Based in the comment of [@Michal Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay), I made various changes in the structure:

1. **Change** the method **to require all the values to change** and update all the *XML*.
2. **Change the global variables** of the class to **make global *FileChannel settingsChannel*** (before was an inline object).
3. **Every operation**, the entire **content of the file it's replaced**, with this steps:

   1. Remove all the content with *.truncate(0)* (**this set the length of the file to 0**)
   2. Update the writer instance with *.flush()* (**If don't, the data don't reach the channel**)
   3. Force the data to reach the disk with *.force(true)* (**If don't, the Writer class save the data in the cache**)
   4. Write the new data in the *XML* file with the *XMLOutputter* (**This doesn't change**)
   5. **Update all again using the 2 and 3 step**.

That it's how i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setElementValue()` method calls `xmlOutput.output(settingsDoc, settingsWriter);` to output the entire document every time there is a change, and that's exactly what is happening. You need to change it so it only outputs the document once, at the end.